# Share on facebook not visible in friends timelines - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have done a facebook sharing in android app follwing way.

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("AKURU APP")

                        .setContentDescription(
                                "Very useful app for KIDS to learn Sinhala")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://facebookobjectlinktomyapp"))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://xequalz.com/images/feature_graphic.png"))
                        .build();




                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
```

And I asked my fried to share on Facebook through my app using his Facebook username and password. The share content is vissible on his time line but not in my time line.

Facebook App is currently in live mode and I'm just wandering whats the issue for this.

Comment: Why would it be visible on your timeline if your friend shares it?

Answer (score 0):

If he shared it in his timeline, it will of course be visible in his timeline and not yours.

However, with pretty much every social action any of your friends do there is a chance you will see it on your news feed.